# Use United States Regional Settings with dd/mm/yyy date format

Tags: 2010

On a current SharePoint site,wWe want to use en-US regional settings, changing only the date format to dd/mm/yyyy. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to change only that. I am sure that there is a way for changing the date formatting for the en-US locale, but haven't found a way to make that change.

Is there a way or am I deluding myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a workaround solution for your problem.

Try this - http://imason.com/imason_Blogs/b/ideas/archive/2008/10/24/modifying-the-default-date-time-format-for-a-sharepoint-2007-site-collection.aspx

What it basically does is to try to find a locale/regional setting that had the date format you need (For eg:- 'fr-CA') and then use the CultrueAndRegionInfoBuilder to copy all the locale settings from en-US to fr-CA.  After this, Change the locale for all the site collections and their sub-sites to use this customized fr-CA culture which is basically en-US using fr-CA's date format.  Deploy it as a feature and activate it into your site.